# How to join 2 tables in django ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I have 2 Tables. **TableA** and **TableB**.

`id` is the primary key in **TableB** and `item_id` is the foreign key in **TableA**.

My task is to find all the `items` from **TableB** where the `id` should match the `item_ids`.

I am able to get all the items with the below queries. But I'd like to understand how to apply joins on the both tables using `select_related` to get the same result.

```py
item_ids = list(TableA.objects.filter(is_active=True).\
                               distinct().\
                               values_list('item_id', flat=True))

items = TableB.objects.filter(Q(id__in=item_ids) & \
                              Q(display_name__isnull=False) & \
                              Q(name__isnull=False)).\
                       values("name", "display_name")
```

model -->> **TableA**

```py
class TableA(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(TableB, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('item',)

class TableB(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I'd like to translate below query into ORM

```
select DISTINCT TableB.name, TableB.display_name
from TableB
inner join TableA on TableA.item_id = TableB.id
where TableA.is_active=true AND
      TableB.display_name is not NULL AND
      TableB.name is not NULL
```

Could someone help me with the query?

Comment: Can you share your model as there is an ORM way to do this

Comment: you are using values. hence you don't need select_related here. you can have more fields in values to get what you want.

Comment: Hi @MohamedElKalioby, I have added more details along with the Demo Models

Comment: Hi @shivankgtm, I would like to apply join here

Comment: why? when you use values, it already take care of select_related

Comment: as per your question, shouldn't it be? `item = models.ForeignKey(TableB, on_delete=models.CASCADE`  ?

Comment: @ArunT Yes, True. Updated the description

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `related_name` attribute in your item foreign key definition.
This way, you don't have to guess what the reverse relation is called from TableB.

```
item = models.ForeignKey(TableB, related_name='tablea', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can find your distinct values in a single query like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

items = TableB.objects.filter(
  Q(tablea__is_active=True) &
  Q(display_name__isnull=False) &
  Q(name__isnull=False)
).values(
  'name', 'display_name'
).distinct(
  'name', 'display_name'
).order_by(
  'name', 'display_name'
)
```